# flutter dart regex, get route name by actual route

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, modular

case: of every page, flutter sends page enter event to server with actual route.

in `more` tab of the app, i'm showing recent pages, with the server's record. getting and pushing page works fine, but i have to get page's name by actual route as below.

if input is (full route)`/customer/5ec24beb410df8000906ab5b`, i'd like to find (route spec) `/customer/:id`. and so i can find the screen name with the route spec. is there regex way or smart way to accomplish this?

wrap-up

- pre-defined routes `/customer/:id`, `/product/:id`
- input `/customer/5ec24beb410df8000906ab5b`
- output 1 -> `/customer/:id` (can't do)
- output 2 -> with output 1, getting route's name by map (can do)

Comment: Can you give some examples of input and what you want to extract from each of these inputs?

Comment: @julemand101 updated.